# Not able to Pass content containing a url with parameters through $_POST

Tags: php, url, post

This is really weird. I have a textbox inside a form. On clicking the submit button, the content of the textbox gets posted to page2.php

If the textbox contains a text like

```
This is a sample url 
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=karnataka+badminton+association+bangalore&ie=UTF-8&ei=w4_lUNWmJozjrAfSkYGYBA&ved=0CAsQ_AUoAA
```

Now when i hit submit, i am echoing the content in page2.php and this is what i get:

```
//echo $_POST['message'];

This is a sample url 
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=karnataka
```

I am getting the message but the URL gets cut after the first '+'. Any ideas how to get this work ?

I even checked with firebug the POST request and there it correctly displays the complete url.

NEW EDIT: 
I am trying this with ajax now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code and a test of the exact code works fine here.

Comment: See here: http://rudiv.se/stack/test.php

Comment: @RudiVisser, thanks. i see it is working fine in your example...i modified my script to use ajax...and it still giving the same problem..i know i am doing a mistake from my side but not able to track it...

Comment: Well then, could you provide us with some code? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the url first. You can use  encodeURIComponent(str) or encodeURI(str) embedded in javascript to do so. See:  [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

You should then use urldecode/rawurldecode to decode the url into its native form. You can also store the decoded form and decode the url in php / javascript as needed. See:http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Appologies for my late reply. Yes, that was exactly the error. When i was passing parameters through javascript, the '+' symbol in the url was clashing with the concatenate '+' of javascript. Thanks.